# How to count embedded array object elements in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "orderNo": "123",
    "bags": [{
            "type": "small",
            "products": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "returnable": true
                }, {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "XYZ"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "type": "big",
            "products": [{
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "PQR",
                    "returnable": true
                }, {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "UVW"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have orders collection where documents are in this format. I want to get a total count of **products** which has the **returnable** flag. e.g: for the above order the count should be **2**. I am very new to MongoDB wanted to know how to write a query to find this out, I have tried few things but did not help:
this is what I tried but not worked:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
     { "$unwind": "$bags" },
     { "$unwind": "$bags.products" },
     { "$unwind": "$bags.products.returnable" },
     
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$bags.products.returnable",
         "count": { "$sum": 1 }
     }}
 ])
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inner array you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to check `returnable` flag and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to get number of such items. For the outer one you can take advantage of [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to sum the values from inner arrays:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            totalReturnable: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$bags",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                $size: {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$$this.products",
                                        as: "prod",
                                        cond: {
                                            $eq: [ "$$prod.returnable", true ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k53rErAa-00)

Comment: Thank you very much, 1 small question: what if I want the count based on the 'returnable' attributes availability not on its true/false value.

Comment: @Souma you can try this way: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-pe84bP6CfR